# Adding border to child changes parent dimensions in css

Tags: html, css

My html code (see below) essentially consists of a `p` child nested in an `article` parent. This paragraph is the only child of the `article`.
Adding a border to the `p` child 'drastically' changes de height of the `article` parent. I use Firefox 36.

CSS element inspection reveals that:

- **without** border around the `p` child, the top and bottom margin of the `p` child are **outside** the `parent`;
- **with** border around the `p` child, the top and bottom margin of the `p` child are **inside** the `parent`.

My Question is: "Why is the `p` child with border completely---including padding, border, and margin---wrapped within its parent and the `p` child without border not?"

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> White space problem </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        Menubar items
    </nav>
    <article>
        <p>
            The CSS border properties allow you to specify the style, size, and color of an element's border.
        </p>
    </article>
    <footer>
        This is the footer
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following CSS:

```
nav
{
    background: #ddddff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}

article
{
    background: #ddffdd;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
//    border: 1px solid black; 
}

p
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
}

footer
{
    background: #ffdddd;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Note the article `border` property-value pair is commented out.
The browser (Firefox 36) outputs a 10px wide white space between the `nav` and `article` and between the `article` and `footer`; this white space is the 10px `p` margin. [The `article`s height is 40px.]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvaqjcrh56lg40m/NoBorder.JPG?dl=0

Adding a border to the `p` child, thus uncommenting `border: 1px solid black;` in the CSS-file, gives the following result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oivjsibzm2om1yt/Border.JPG?dl=0

There is no with space. [The `article`s height is now 62px = 40px + 2 x 1px border + 2 x 10px margin.]

Just for clarity: my question is not about getting rid of the white space but rather why the browser changes the articles dimensions depending on whether `p` child has a border or not. This seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me to see what happened: it is a border collapse issue.

Comment: I meant margin collapse (not border collapse) ...

Answer (score 0):

as an quick solution you can use outline in pace of border

```
outline: 1px solid black;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are adding the border to `article`, not `p`.
Since the `p` element has a margin of `10px` all around, there is resulting whitespace above and below it. When the `article` has a `border` applied to it, the child's (in this case `p`) top/bottom edges are defined to be the same as the parent, hence why the background fills up.. That's how I understand it anyways, feel free to correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: Yup, I never said it was white

Comment: The margin is transparent, not white! Without border, `p` and `article` margins collapse, thus the `article` 'inherits' the `p` margin, and you see the white colour of the `body` through it. With border, no collapse occurs,  the `p` has a margin (the `article` doesn't) and you see the green colour of the `article` through it.

Comment: Yes, I know that... I never said the margin was white :/

Comment: I see, you didn't say the margin was white! And I did add the border to the `article` instead of `p`. I think things are clear te me now.